# Cascaded Op Amp Problem

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I have seen an op amp problem and I made a representation of it in LTspice.
[image]
***Attention!*** Vout is not grounded, I had made a mistake. Sorry for this.

The problem wants us to find Vout. To solve it, I used KCL and Nodal Analysis. Here is my solution:

[image]

I feel like something is wrong or missing. Is my result correct? How can I solve it with another way?

*Note:* Please do not care model name of the op amps.

Comment: Your calculation is good.

Comment: 5 and 10 ohm resistors are not practical for just about any model of op-amp- that would cause 200mA to flow if Vx was not grounded. Since Vx is grounded, Vx = 0 and Vout = 0.  Other than that you've got it.

Comment: Why are Vx and Vout ... grounded ?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I see now. So the answer of the problem (if I didn't remember it wrong) must be zero, right?

Comment: @Antonio51 I don't know. The problem is like that if I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: Yes, especially since Vout is grounded. Unless the problem specifies an ideal op-amp in which case it's indeterminate since an ideal op-amp could supply infinite current. I  doubt an instructor would pose a problem as you drew it though. It's kind of a trick question, if so.

Comment: @Mert it is unlikely, to say the least, that the outputs of both opamps are shorted to ground in the problem

Comment: @SpehroPefhany What if Vout did not grounded and these op amps are ideal, what would be the answer?

Comment: If Vout and Vx are not grounded, as I said, your calculation is correct for ideal op amps. If Vout *or* Vx (or both) are grounded then Vout = 0.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I am sure that Vx is grounded. I was not sure for Vout, so I want to ask again. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that \$V_x \$ and \$V_{out}\$ **aren't grounded** (that would be weird for a problem like this) your solution is correct. Assuming ideal op amps: -

The gain of the first amplifier is \$A_{v1}=-\frac{5\Omega}{10\Omega} = -\frac{1}{2} \: \frac{\text{V}}{\text{V}} \$

The gain of the second amplifier is \$A_{v2} =-\frac{2\text{k}\Omega}{1\text{k}\Omega} =-2 \: \frac{\text{V}}{\text{V}}\$

So the total gain is \$A_{v,\text{total}} = A_{v1}A_{v2}=1 \Rightarrow V_o=V_{in}A_{v,\text{total}}=2\text{V}\$

Comment: Yes, probably Vout is not grounded. I remebered it wrong. But Vx is grounded. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Mert if Vx really is grounded, then U1 is (or will soon be) dead, and your Vout is 0V.